# Use Public Variable Globally

Tags: c++, header, include, public

I'm attempting to modify a MIPS simulator to display the contents of its registers during run time.  My question refers to the way in which I plan to do this.  So...

I have a file, file1.cpp and file2.cpp.  There is a local public variable in file1.cpp called

```
typedef long ValueGPR;
ValueGPR reg[33];
```

that I want to access in file2.cpp.  Each of these files have a header file.  File2.cpp contains a function which iteratively tracks the execution of a program instruction by instruction making this the perfect place to insert a printf("REG[%d]:%d\n",i,reg[i]); statement or something like that but reg is a local variable in file1.cpp.  How do I stitch together something that will allow me to access this reg variable?

This is what both files actually look like (after thinking about this a bit more):
"File1.h"

```
typedef long ValueGPR;
...
class ThreadContext {
    ...
    public:
        ValueGPR reg[33];
        ...
    ...
}
...
```

"File2.cpp"

```
...
#include ".../ThreadContext.h"
...
long ExecutionFlow::exeInst(void) {
    ...
    //ADD PRINTF OF reg[1] - reg[32] HERE
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: Woops, I screwed up my description...
So, reg is used in file1.cpp but it is defined in the following way in file1.h:
`typedef long ValueGPR;
public: 
 ValueGPR reg[33];`

Comment: So, if this is the case can I just replace public: ValueGPR reg[33]; with extern ValueGPR reg[33];?

Comment: @Dan: If `reg` is a member of a class (which it seems to be judging from your comments), then changing it into a global would be a bad idea - you'll get incorrect behaviour if you have more than one instance of the class. Instead, you should find a way to pass either `reg`, or the object that contains it, by reference to the function in `file2.cpp` that wants access to it.

Comment: You're correct, reg is part of a class.  Is it possible to define a global pointer within the object containing reg?  How would one go about doing this and then access it within file2.cpp?

Comment: Please post the declaration of the classes.  I'm getting confused.

Comment: File1.h looks like this:

typedef long ValueGPR;
...
class ThreadContext {
    ...
    public:
        ValueGPR reg[33];
        ...
    ...
}
...` 

File2.cpp looks like this:

 `...
#include ".../ThreadContext.h"
...
long ExecutionFlow::exeInst(void) {
    ...
    //ADD PRINTF OF reg[1] - reg[32] HERE
    ...
}
...  (how do I add code tags?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cogwheel's answer is correct, but your comment indicates some possibility of confusion, so perhaps it's better to clarify a bit:

## file1.h:

```
#ifndef FILE1_H_INCLUDED
#define FILE1_H_INCLUDED

typedef long ValueGPR;
extern ValueGPR reg[];
#define NUM_REGS 33

#endif
```

## file1.c:

```
#include "file1.h"

ValueGPR reg[NUM_REGS];
```

## file2.c:

```
#include "file1.h"

/* ... */
for (i=0; i<NUM_REGS; i++)
    show(reg[i]);
```

Edit: Given the additional point that `reg` is really a member of a class, the code above clearly won't work, though the general idea remains the same. For a class member, you'd need to deal with the class as a whole, not just the `reg` itself. Taking a wild stab at what things *might* look like, you could have something like:

## file1.h:

```
// include guard here

class CPU_state { 
public:
    typedef long ValueGPR;
    static const int num_regs = 33;
    ValueGPR reg[num_regs];

    //or, preferably:

    // std::vector<ValueGPR> regs;
    // CPU_state() : regs(num_regs) {}
    // ...
};

extern CPU_state cpu;
```

## file1.cpp:

```
#include "file1.h"
CPU_state cpu;
```

## file2.cpp:

```
#include "file1.h"

for (int i=0; i<cpu.num_regs; i++)
    show(cpu.reg[i]);
```

If you might create more than one CPU at a time, then you'll probably need to pass a pointer or reference to a CPU_state (or whatever you call it) rather than relying on a global instance like this code uses.

Comment: I've tried this with error.  I think is has to do with the fact that reg is contained within a class inside of file1.h  I forgot to mention this important detail...

Comment: So, the file1.h file already had a "typedef CPU_state cpu" line, but when I append "extern" to this line I am told that there are multiple storage classes in this declaration.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Dan: you probably don't want it to be a typedef, just `extern CPU_state cpu;`.

Comment: It turns out that there was already an oject defined within file2.cpp which allowed me to access the reg variable I was after.

Answer (score 4):

I would move the typedef into file1.h along with the following declaration:

```
extern ValueGPR reg[];
```

Leave the `ValueGPR reg[33];` in file1.cpp.